# transform numbers in href tel tag

Tags: regex

I have a directory with hundreds of phone numbers with the form "xx.xx.xx.xx.xx". where "x" are numbers from 0 to 9. Groups of 2 numbers are separated by a dot. I'm looking for a regex that would integrate the last 9 numbers in a syntax like this

```
<a href="tel:+33XXXXXXXXX">xx.xx.xx.xx.xx</a>
```

The French International extension (+33) replaces the first number that always starts with a 0. I would like to keep the original format between the tags if possible.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Regex on OSX Terminal

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Test:

```
$ echo "01.23.45.67.89" \
| sed -re 's,^([0-9])([0-9])\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})$,<a href="tel:+33\2\3\4\5\6">\1\2.\3.\4.\5.\6</a>,'
<a href="tel:+33123456789">01.23.45.67.89</a>
```

In practical use: with a file that has one "xx.xx.xx.xx.xx" per line

```
$ cat phone_numbers.txt \
| sed -re 's,^([0-9])([0-9])\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})$,<a href="tel:+33\2\3\4\5\6">\1\2.\3.\4.\5.\6</a>,'
<a href="tel:+33123456789">01.23.45.67.89</a>
```

*The latter not tested.*

Answer (score 0):

If Notepad++ is an option for you, you can do the following:

(Note that can be used in many tools):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\d)(\d)\.(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\.(\d\d)$`
- Replace with: `<a href="33$2$3$4$5$6">$0</a>`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/2JBLub/1)

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
    (\d)        # group 1, first digit (zero)
    (\d)        # group 2, second digit (area code)
    \.          # a dot
    (\d\d)      # group 3, 2 digits
    \.          # a dot
    (\d\d)      # group 4, 2 digits
    \.          # a dot
    (\d\d)      # group 5, 2 digits
    \.          # a dot
    (\d\d)      # group 6, 2 digits
$               # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
<a href="       # literally
33              # 33
$2              # content of group 2, the second digit (area code)
$3              # content of group 3
$4              # content of group 4
$5              # content of group 5
$6              # content of group 6
">              # literally
$0              # content of group 0, the whole match
</a>            # end tag
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The OSX terminal returns the following error.

Last login: Tue Apr 21 16:07:46 on ttys000
pc9:~ MY-USERNAME$ cd ~/Downloads/sample_dir/tel.html
-bash: cd: /Users/MY-USERNAME/Downloads/sample_dir/tel.html: Not a directory
pc9:~ MY-USERNAME$ $ echo "01.23.45.67.89" \

> | sed -re 's,^([0-9])([0-9]).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2})$,\1\2.\3.\4.\5.\6,'
>   -bash: $: command not found
>   sed: illegal option -- r
>   usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
>          sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
>   pc9:~ MY-USERNAME$ 01.23.45.67.89
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'